# Integral = f(a) + const

Tags: integration

Fairly simple question, but I can not think of an example.
Let $f_a(x)$ be an integrable function, that depends on some parameter $a$.

I'm wondering if there exists a function such that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_a(x) \, {\rm d}x = f(a) + {\rm const}$$
i.e. that the result has a constant term independent of an $a$-dependent term, of course both $\neq 0$.
Thanks

EDIT: Of course I should have said, that simple constructions by addition of an $a$-independent term does not count!
What I mean is more something like $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(ax)}{x} \, {\rm d}x = \pi \, .$$

Also worth mentioning is, that it can not be of the form
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(ax) \, {\rm d}x = \frac{1}{a} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(z) \, {\rm d}z \, .
$$

Likewise as the $\sin$ example something like
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(ax) \, \frac{{\rm d}x}{x}
$$
will always be independent of $a$.
Atm I'm tempted to say this is not possible, but I can not proof it :-/

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_a(x) = e^{-|ax|} + e^{-|x|}$, then

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (e^{-|ax|} + e^{-|x|}) dx = \frac{2}{|a|} + 2, a \not= 0$$

That satisfies your condition if I understand it correctly.

Comment: Yes of course, edited.

Answer (score 0):

Of course:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ -\frac{x^2}{2a^2}}+e^{ -\frac{x^2}{2}}dx = a\sqrt{2\pi} + \sqrt{2\pi}$$